# Calculating number of words in a string in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

I have written a simple plsql function to calculate the number of words in a string.

```
create or replace function GetWordsCount(instr in varchar2) return varchar2 
is
count number;
  outstr varchar2(2000);
  l1 number;
  l2 number;
begin
  outstr := rtrim(ltrim(REGEXP_REPLACE (instr, '\s{2,}', ' ')));
  l1 := length(outstr);
  l2 := lenth(replace(outstr,' ',''));
  count := l1-l2+1;
  return count;
end;
```

Although when I test this function in sql using a query it works but when I try to build as a function it gives me the following errors.

```
SQLDEV:LINK:VS_DEV_NAV:FUNCTION:GETWORDSCOUNT:5:10:5,10:oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.DefaultDrillLink    "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "VARCHAR2" to continue.
"
SQLDEV:LINK:VS_DEV_NAV:FUNCTION:GETWORDSCOUNT:5:24:5,24:oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.DefaultDrillLink    "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
"
SQLDEV:LINK:VS_DEV_NAV:FUNCTION:GETWORDSCOUNT:8:10:8,10:oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.DefaultDrillLink    "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
"
SQLDEV:LINK:VS_DEV_NAV:FUNCTION:GETWORDSCOUNT:9:6:9,6:oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.DefaultDrillLink  "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
"
```

Please suggest what the issue could be.

================================================================================Updated the return and changed the default count variable to someother variable and it worked.

But now am facing a logical issue here:

```
declare 
c number;
begin
  c:=getwordscount('Hello World.Welcome to the Pl/Sql world!');
  dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
```

When I run this it gives me output as 6, although 7 words are there, my word calculation is based on space count and so it failed.

Can someone suggest me a better logic to overcome this scenarios?

## Thank You!

Thanks,
Dex.

Comment: You might try `return number` in the declaration.

Comment: SQL is not a good platform to do word counts.  Is there an app layer or something that you can do that in?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this... decide what other characters should NOT be part of words, and add them to the match pattern. Make sure to escape the characters that may have a special meaning, like - and (.

```
with a (test_text) as 
   (
    select 'Hello World.Peace  on Earth!  Hurray!.. .# This is good'
    from dual
   )
select regexp_count(test_text, '[^ .?!#\()]+') as word_count from a
/
WORD_COUNT
----------
         9
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `regexp_count` function with the pattern **\w+** which means, any-word character with a minimum of one occurence and an undefined maximum:

```
SELECT regexp_count('I have written a simple plsql function to calculate the number of words in a string.'
                   ,'\w+') 
  FROM dual
```